# Accuracy for Azure Text Analytics in Portuguese

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I'm using Azure Text Analytics - Sentiment Analysis in Portuguese. But, since yesterday, all the sentences are classified between 50% to 60%, even negative ones! Is there a problem with the classifier?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We identified an issue, have a fix for it, and will be deploying it today. So you should have good sentiment analysis in Portuguese later today or tomorrow.

Luis Cabrera
Program Manager, Text Analytics

Comment: Thanks, Luis! Tomorrow I'll test it again!

Comment: This issue is now fixed